# C++17 fold expression in cout

Tags: c++, c++17, fold-expression

I am learning the new c++17 fold expression and I saw this code from [c++17 fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). I would like to know why this code work :

```
template<typename ...Args>
void printer(Args&&... args) {
    (std::cout << ... << args) << '\n';
}
```

but not this one :

```
template<typename ...Args>
void printer(Args&&... args) {
    (std::cout << args << ...) << '\n';
}
```

which could seems logic too and would reverse the print order in my opinion.

Comment: `std::cout << ... << args` matches (4) `init op ... op pack`. `std::cout << args << ...` matches none of the valid forms.

Comment: And why people choose to not create this form ? how then could we get the parameters in a reverse way ?

Comment: "*how then could we get the parameters in a reverse way ?*" You'd have to write some reversing tool, which would be very difficult to write. Normal pack expansion has no way to expand the pack in reverse order either.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not that difficult...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As seen on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), binary folds can have the following two forms:

[image: Screenshot from cppreference/fold]

Where `E` is the *pack expression* and `I` is the *initialization expression*.

---

There is no binary fold that matches your `(std::cout << args << ...)`, which has the form of `(I op E op ...)`.

Comment: Hi - I am aware this is a long time ago, but could someone shows me what will ```(std::cout << args << ...)``` look like after expanding? I just don't get it no matter how many times I read cppref. It seems like it's going to expand to ```(((std::cout << arg1) << arg2) << arg3)``` which looks totally valid. The other way around would be ```(std::cout << (arg1 << (arg2 << arg3)))``` but it works. HOW???

Comment: @Hydrogen: `I` is `std::cout`, `op` is `<<`, and `E` is `args...`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought the "which" word you mean in your original text referring to ```(std::cout << args << ...)```.

Answer (score 0):

Binary fold works just fine with `<<` operator. Try this out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>


// g++ -c -std=c++17 fold_cout.cpp
// g++ -std=c++17 fold_cout.cpp -o fldcout.exe

template<typename ...Ts,
         std::size_t... I>
void print(std::tuple<Ts...> const &tpl, std::index_sequence<I...>) // tag dispatching
{
    auto formatter = [](auto const& elem) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << elem << ',';
        return ss.str();
    };
    std::cout<<'(';
    ///((std::cout<<std::get<I>(tpl)<<','), ...); // fold on comma op; okay
    ///(std::cout<<...<<(std::get<I>(tpl))); // fold on `<<` op;
    //                                          okay, but separator is problematic
    //                                          (needs special formatter lambda)
    (std::cout<<...<<formatter(std::get<I>(tpl))); 
    std::cout<<")\n";
}

template<typename ...Ts>
void print(std::tuple<Ts...> const& tpl)
{
    print(tpl, std::make_index_sequence< sizeof...(Ts) >{});
}

int main(void)
{
    std::tuple t{ 13, 17, 3.14, std::string{"Hello"} };

    print(t);
    std::cout << "Done!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You can also obtain the desired effect by folding on the comma operator `,`:

```
template<typename ...Args>
void foo(Args&&...ts)
{
    std::cout<<"T list: ";
    ((std::cout<<std::forward<Args>(ts)<<','),...);
    std::cout<<'\n';
}
```